# How to obtain a string equals to each first letter of words in a sentence IN SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have words separated with a space in a column  like 
`apple orange banana` I need the first letters as the result will be something like :

```
aob
```

Comment: What version of `sql server` are you using?

Comment: @RyanWilson Microsoft SQL Server 2012 , I updated the tag

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012). As STRING_SPLIT would probably have been recommanded if you were on a higher version of SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please post your attempts?

Comment: String processing is *not* T-SQL's strong suit. Is there a reason this has to be done in the database?

Comment: I try to insert in a FullName column of a table,
from another table the name(watson) and firstname(mary jane) from another column,  repecting this format MJ.WASTSON. @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't want to do write a program to extract transform and insert data.

Answer (score 1):

First, split your text. I recommend some function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split(@text nvarchar(MAX),@separator nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
WITH Indexed AS
(
    SELECT 1 N, CAST(1 AS bigint) S, CHARINDEX(@separator, @text, 1) E WHERE @text IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1, E+DATALENGTH(@separator)/2, CHARINDEX(@separator, @text, E+DATALENGTH(@separator)/2) FROM Indexed WHERE E>S
), Token AS
(
    SELECT N, SUBSTRING(@text, S, CASE WHEN E=0 THEN DATALENGTH(@text)/2 ELSE E-S END) T FROM Indexed
)
SELECT * FROM Token
```

*If you are using SQL 2016 and greater, use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.*

Then, you can select first character of every word and join. See following example:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE (T nvarchar(100));
INSERT @Sample VALUES (N'apple orange banana'),(N'dog cat');

SELECT (SELECT SUBSTRING(T,1,1) [*] FROM Split(T,N' ') FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM @Sample
```

Result:

```
(no column name)
------
aob
dc
```

Comment: Just to be a smart aleck ;-) `STRING SPLIT()` migth not return in the expected order, at least this is not guaranteed. With SQL-Server 2016 it's better to use `OPENJSON` and transform the CSV into a JSON array first. The `key` will reflect the item's position. Btw: My answer does the concatenation within XML. Within XML the element's order is part of the document and therefore guaranteed. [Here's an `OPENJSON` 
 example with performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51401153/5089204)

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using a little XML.  You could also use ParseName() provided you trap any periods in the string.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table(ID int,LastName varchar(50),FirstName varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Waston','Mary Jane')

Select A.ID
      ,NewValue = upper(
                      concat(
                            xmlData.value('/x[1]','varchar(1)')
                           ,xmlData.value('/x[2]','varchar(1)')
                           ,xmlData.value('/x[3]','varchar(1)')
                           ,xmlData.value('/x[4]','varchar(1)')
                           ,'.'
                           ,LastName
                       )
                   )
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace(A.FirstName,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' )) ) B(xmlData)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  NewValue
1   MJ.WASTON
```

> **EDIT - Added ParseName() option**

```
Select A.ID
      ,NewValue = upper(concat(Pos1,Pos2,Pos3,Pos4,'.',LastName))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = left(parsename(tStr,4),1)
                      ,Pos2 = left(parsename(tStr,3),1)
                      ,Pos3 = left(parsename(tStr,2),1)
                      ,Pos4 = left(parsename(tStr,1),1)
                 From  ( values(replace(FirstName,' ','.'))) B1(tStr)
             ) B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare REGEX function in your DB (not native with SQL SERVER).

Using regexp_replace

```
select regexp_replace('apple orange banana','(\\w)(\\w* ?)','$1')
```

return

```
aob
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest will be this:

Here a *mockup-table* with two rows to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourWords VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('apple orange banana'),('one two three');
```

--That is the query:

```
SELECT m.ID
      ,REPLACE(Casted.query('for $w in /x return substring($w,1,1)').value('.','varchar(max)'),' ','')
FROM @mockup m
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(m.YourWords,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted);
```

The idea behind:
The string `apple orange banana` is tranformed to `<x>apple</x><x>orange</x><x>banana</x>` and is casted to XML, which allows to use `XQuery`.
Now we use `.query()` on the XML with a simple `FLWOR` statement. It tells the engine: *run through each value of `/x` and return just the first letter*. Calling `value()` on this with a `.` as `XPath` will return the values *in one*.
We need a final `REPLACE()` to get rid of blanks, which would otherwise appear as `a o b` instead of `aob`.