# Result order of string_split?

Tags: sql-server, split, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

Now I found this great `string_split()` function, and then I learned that **the output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.**.  This renders the function useless for me.

Is there maybe a workaround?

**EDIT -** Example:

```
SELECT value FROM String_Split('b,a,c', ',')
```

In this case I want this result in this order:

```
value
------
b
a
c
```

However, according to Microsoft, this order is **not guaranteed**. So how can I get exactly this result?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749515/10532500

Comment: *"So how can I get exactly this result?"* by using a solution that provides ordinal positions; which `STRING_SPLIT` does not. It's lack of this information has been complained about a lot since it's introduction in SQL Server 2016, and MS seem to not want to add it to the function. I suggest looking up `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`, for example.

Comment: `'a'` is "less than" `'b'`, @SurajKumar , that answer assumes that ordinal position and value order are the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Original answer:**

You may try to use an approach, based on JSON. You need to transform the input string into a valid JSON array (`b,a,c` is transformed into `["b","a","c"]`) and then parse this array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`, and based on the documentation, the `key` column is *an nvarchar(4000) value that contains the name of the specified property or the index of the element in the specified array*.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @StringToSplit VARCHAR(100) = 'b,a,c';

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@StringToSplit, ',', '","'), '"]'))
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])
```

Result:

```
value
b
a
c
```

If you have quotes in the input string, try with the following statement, using `STRING_ESCAPE()`:

```
DECLARE @StringToSplit VARCHAR(100) = '"b",''a'',c';

SELECT [value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@StringToSplit, 'json'), ',', '","'), '"]'))
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])
```

Result:

```
value
"b"
'a'
c
```

**Update:**

Starting from SQL Server 2022, the `STRING_SPLIT()` function supports an optional third parameter (`enable_ordinal`). The parameter is an `int` or `bit` expression that serves as a flag to enable or disable the `ordinal` output column. A value of `1` enables the `ordinal` column. If `enable_ordinal` is omitted, `NULL`, or has a value of `0`, the `ordinal` column is disabled.

```
SELECT [value]
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@StringToSplit, ',', 1)
ORDER BY [ordinal]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great solution! Just to be complete: If the original string contains quotes, then they must be escaped?

Comment: Wow thanks, is that great! Learned now there is an escaping function for specialized types like json!

Comment: @askolotl Yes, but currently `STRING_ESCAPE()` supports only JSON.

Comment: What is it about this JSON approach that guarantees order?  I don't believe it does.

Comment: @wBob It's in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value) - _When you call OPENJSON with the default schema, ... the function returns a table with the following columns:a) Key. An nvarchar(4000) value that contains the name of the specified property or the index of the element in the specified array. The key column has a BIN2 collation, ..._.

Comment: This solution is great!

Answer (score 4):

If there are no duplicates in the string you are splitting you can use the below.

```
DECLARE @StringToSplit VARCHAR(100) = 'b,a,c';

SELECT  
    value 
FROM String_Split(@StringToSplit, ',') d
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(','+  value+ ',',  ',' + @StringToSplit + ',' )
```

Comment: Interesting answer, but I have duplicates.

Comment: @askolotl - you're out of luck then and should look for another string splitter than `String_Split` until it gets this missing functionality added

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, here the logic may be different for the ordering but order by clause works the same as it works on the table.

Comment: @SurajKumar - Nobody is saying that `ORDER BY` can't be used with `String_Split` - the missing functionality is an index column saying the order that the split item was found. Ideally the function would return the same result set as `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('b',1),('a',2),('c',3)) V(value, idx)` then we could order by `idx`

Comment: @SurajKumar Exactly what Martin says. The split_string function is only returning the value, but it is not telling you in which position the string was found. There is an index column missing in the result.

Comment: If there are duplicates, you can use the method Ronen Ariely [describes here](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/223/T-SQL-Playing-with-STRING_SPLIT-function.aspx). Please note, however, that he himself does not recommend this method due to performance issues. You might be better off using something other than the built in function.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!-- language: lang-sql --> 
SELECT p.[Id], [p].[Body], [x].[value], x.[RN]
FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [p]
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT ss.[value], 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [p].[Id] ORDER BY [p].[Id]) AS RN <--------- (SORT)
FROM STRING_SPLIT([p].[Body], ' ') AS [ss]
      ) AS x
```

Comment: Can you please format the code and explain the logic behind?