# Grab the last value of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2017.

I have a `Description` column in my table which may contain multiple colors. I need to grab the last color that appears in the string. Is there way to order it per value that is parsed from the description column descending?

```
SELECT DISTINCT color   
FROM (VALUES ('Dove'), ('Frost')) t(Color)
WHERE 'jgkgh FROST tohjgkhg DOVE gfsgfgs' LIKE CONCAT('%', t.Color, '%') 
  AND t.Color IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: use string_Split() to parse out the description column into it's own rows with an ordinal and then get the max ordinal with a color inlist. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15; then using that ordinal get the color.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
SELECT distinct color , charindex(' ' + reverse(color)+' ', ' ' + reverse('jgkgh FROST tohjgkhg DOVE gfsgfgs dove frost') + ' ') as rvrscharidx 
FROM (VALUES('Dove'),('Frost'))t(Color)
WHERE   'jgkgh FROST tohjgkhg DOVE gfsgfgs dove frost' LIKE CONCAT('%',t.Color,'%') AND t.Color IS NOT NULL 
order by rvrscharidx
```

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:
Uses table value function STRING_SPLIT()

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT('jgkgh FROST tohjgkhg DOVE gfsgfgs', ' ', 1))

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CTE 
WHERE VALUE in ('Dove', 'Frost')
ORDER BY Ordinal Desc
```

Reference Example:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ', 1);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: String_split does **not** guarantee order. The doc is unfortunately confusing since it includes syntax that is valid for only some versions of sql server.

Comment: The more you know! https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/string-split-and-ordered-results/233480  I had no idea.  so JSON approach may work better... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60129782/result-order-of-string-split

Comment: As an alternative:  XML/XQuery.

Comment: Directly from the official documentation: "...The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only)...."

Comment: FYI the *enable_ordinal* option is supposedly in the SQL Server 2022 release.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using XML/XQuery. Their data model is based on *ordered sequences*. Exactly what we need.

1. `CROSS APPLY` converts *Description* column into XML data type.
2. To get the last token, we are using the following XPath predicate:
   `/root/r[last()]`
3. To sort colors, we are using FLWOR expression with the `order by data($x) descending` clause.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Description] VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([Description]) VALUES
('Blue Black Red'),
('Cyan Green White');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

-- without sorting
SELECT t.*
    , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS lastColor
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE([Description], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS tab(c);

-- with sorting
SELECT t.*
    , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS lastColor
    , c
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE([Description], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('<root>
        {
            for $x in /root/r
            order by data($x) descending
            return $x
        }
      </root>
      ')) AS tab(c);
```

**Output without sorting**

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| ID |   Description    | lastColor |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Blue Black Red   | Red       |
|  2 | Cyan Green White | White     |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

**Output with sorting**

```
+----+------------------+-----------+
| ID |   Description    | lastColor |
+----+------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Blue Black Red   | Black     |
|  2 | Cyan Green White | Cyan      |
+----+------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and fastest way to solve this:

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Description] VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl ([Description]) VALUES
('Red Blue Black'),
('White Green');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

```
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.*, LastColor = RIGHT(t.Description,CHARINDEX(SPACE(1),REVERSE(t.Description)))
FROM @tbl AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID   Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     LastColor
---- ------------------
1    Red Blue Black                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Black
2    White Green                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Green
```