# Split multiple values in columns and multiple columns in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with rows like these:

| Name | Text | Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 | Loc4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe;Wayne;Black | Spain | Italy | US | NULL |
| Michael | Scott;White | France | Germany | NULL | NULL |

So, the `Text` column can have from 0 to 4 "values", separated by `;`, and the `LocX` column will be populated as a result.

I was able to reach this output using `STRING_SPLIT` (for example for the first row):

| Name | Text | Loc1 | Loc2 | Loc3 | Loc4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | Spain | Italy | US | NULL |
| John | Wayne | Spain | Italy | US | NULL |
| John | Black | Spain | Italy | US | NULL |

But I would like to have this result:

| Name | Text | Loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | Spain |
| John | Wayne | Italy |
| John | Black | US |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There need to be column(s) which determine the pairings between the name/text and chosen locations.

Comment: What _version_ of SQL Server (`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion');` will do)? And do you have some constraint that dictates the number of strings in `Text` matches the number of `LocN` columns populated?

Comment: I *hope* the reason you're working to do this is to fix your design; if it's not make it so that it is.

Comment: (In SQL Server 2022, for example, [this is pretty easy](https://dbfiddle.uk/CZV3fo9O). In earlier versions, it's a little more complicated.)

Comment: *the Text field can have from 0 to 4 "values"* - no. it has *one* value, the text string that's stored there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, the values come from an external system in which is mandatory to have fo example 3 strings and 3 locs

Comment: @Stu this is the reason why I wrote "values" instead of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hopefully* you are on the latest version of SQL Server (2022 at time of writing), as this means you have access to both `STRING_SPLIT` and *importantly* its ordinal parameter. In this case, getting the results you want is quite simple; split the string (on the semicolon (`;`)) and then use a `CASE`  expression (or as [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77866336/split-multiple-field-values-in-colums-and-multiple-colums-in-one-ms-sql/77866424#comment137273472_77866424) the `CHOOSE` function) to get the relevant value for `Loc`:

```sql
SELECT V.Name,
       V.Text,
       V.Loc1,
       V.Loc2,
       V.Loc3,
       V.Loc4
INTO dbo.DenormalisedTable
FROM (VALUES('John','Doe;Wayne;Black','Spain','Italy','US',CONVERT(varchar(10),NULL)),
            ('Michael','Scott;White','France','Germany',NULL,NULL))V(Name,Text,Loc1,Loc2,Loc3,Loc4);
GO

SELECT DT.Name,
       SS.value,
       CASE SS.ordinal WHEN 1 THEN DT.Loc1
                       WHEN 2 THEN DT.Loc2
                       WHEN 3 THEN DT.Loc3
                       WHEN 4 THEN DT.Loc4
       END AS Loc
FROM dbo.DenormalisedTable DT
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(DT.Text,';',1) SS;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.DenormalisedTable;
```

If you aren't on SQL Server 2022, then you can't use `STRING_SPLIT` as the order is *not* guaranteed. Instead you'll need to use a different method. That might be a ["JSON Splitter"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132099/2029983), or a tally splitter like [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

It's also worth noting, as alluded to in the comments, that this *assumes* that the `loc*` columns have been populated **properly**. If, for example, you have a value `'Jane;Sally'` in `Text`, but `Loc1` and `Loc3` and populated with the values `'UK'` and `'Japan'`, then Sally would have a value of `NULL` for `Loc`.

Comment: Or using `CHOOSE` https://dbfiddle.uk/92C-tKnA

Comment: Interestingly, `CHOOSE` causes an additional Compute Scalar, @Charlieface . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h1ZksLrS) (Not saying `CHOOSE` is the wrong choice, I just expected identical plans.)

Comment: Seems to be because of the implicit conversion from `bigint` to `int` https://dbfiddle.uk/p9yHfQFe I doubt it's significant.

Comment: @ThomA unfortunately I have sql server 14 :(

Comment: So you'll have to a different method, such as the JSON Splitter or tally splitter I link to, @PNelli ; the solution is the same, you just need to use a different function to get the value split with its ordinal position. As you're using SQL server 2017, you have the choice of either (as JSON support was added in 2016, and `LEAD` support in 2012).

Comment: @ThomA done with JSON Splitter :) Thanks!